# Beginner's question about fuel control of a rocket

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I am very new to control and mostly just reading Bellmann's stuff. He has some nice examples and writes really clearly, although there are times when his notation gets a little crazy.

Does anyone know of an example with, say, a rocket and its fuel control?

For example, suppose a rocket is given a certain amount of fuel and the pilot wants to use the fuel so that he runs out just as he lands. The amount of fuel can be whatever to start and constant velocity may not get rid of all the fuel. Having left over fuel can be viewed as just as bad as not having enough fuel so the issue of crashing doesn't come into the problem. For example,  it could have  been an initial amount of water out of the pilot's thermos and he has to drink continuously so that he finishes the water exactly as they land. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain this is a well-defined problem. Given some amount of fuel, you can potentially choose infinitely many different paths such that you land with no fuel remaining, assuming the terminal point is reachable. Therefore both the Bellman and the Pontryagin approaches might break down. Is there maybe some other performance index you'd want to measure in addition to the fuel? Maybe minimum time to land? Or maybe minimum position error at the terminal point under some aero or thrust uncertainties?

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help. I have to think of a better way of explaining my problem so your comment helped. I'll check it so that people don't keep coming to this question. I will also try to think of a better way of explaining my question.

Comment: Since the response was only a comment, I can't check it. is there a way to close the question ? Thanks for help from anyone.

Comment: Rewrote it as an actual answer. Also, I think understand what type of problem you are going for and I keep mentioning Pontryagin because I believe it will be significantly easier than Bellman. However, that's just my opinion and I could be not fully grasping what you are going for.

Comment: @Michael Sparapany: Thanks for your help. I checked your answer even though my question needs reformulating. I like Bellman's various material but, since that's really DP approach,  do you know of a decent book for pontryagin, calculalus of variations ? I don't mind somewhat mathy book but I don't want something at the level of say Aoki.  He's got a few but the ones I've glanced at are too advanced for me, especially at this stage. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the *Moon Lander* example on the first few pages of Evans's [lecture notes on optimal control](https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: Start from chapter 4 with Rodrigo's post on Evan's notes. [Applied Optimal Control](https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Optimal-Control-Arthur-Bryson/dp/0891162283) is pretty much the standard in this field. I found Longuski's [Optimal Control with Aerospace Applications](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461489443) to be very readable, and it has some MATLAB examples included in the appendix so it's really easy to see the application.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the recommedations. I have tons of books but recommendations are appreciated because mine go from really hard mathematical ones like aoki all the way to dirk which I find quite readable.  Bellman is surprisingly quite readable also. I do have evans but haven't gone through it so I'll move from Bellman to that. All the best.

Comment: Also, after I go through Evans, I will come back with hopefully a better worded problem. It's quite amazing to have facilities like this on the net. I think of freshman year college when one guy in the 10 person suite had a PC. (1984-85 ).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you don't have a well enough defined problem. When you start getting into Bellman and Pontryagin's work, you're getting into a specialization of control theory known as optimal control. With your specific problem, a rocket may land while expending all of its fuel in any number of ways. That is, there are an infinite number of paths it may take. Optimal control usually only works under the assumption that there exists 1 locally optimal solution. Refine the problem with a performance index such as minimum time to land. You can then include expending all fuel as a terminal constraint.

On the other hand, if you do not want to include any additional performance measurements, you can solve the problem by picking any of the infinite paths available. To do this, you won't want to use Bellman or Pontryagin.